# How to Redirect file to another path

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect https://example.com/sitemap.xml  to https://example.com/sites/default/files/sitemap/sitemap.xml

How can I do so? I tried following rule but it is not working

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.xml$ /sites/default/files/sitemap/$1 [NC L]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" ? Does it redirect the uri to an unexpected destination?

Comment: yes! it redirect to https://example.com/sites/default/files/sitemap/sitemap instead of https://example.com/sites/default/files/sitemap/sitemap.xml

Answer (score 0):

Works for me!
RewriteRule ^([^/]+.xml)$ sites/default/files/sitemap/$1 [NC,L]